# Sending email with flag not working

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I have an Outlook 2007 macro that sends an email with flag for recipient but it doesn't work anymore.

I made a change to the code by mistake and now it doesn't work anymore.

The recipient doesn't see the email in TO DO and it doesn't show red on the email list.

```
Sub fff()
    Dim outApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Dim datDue As Date
    datDue = DateAdd("d", 7, Date)


     Set OutMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "me@yyy.com"
        .Subject = "test"
        .HtmlBody = "msg"

        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .FlagStatus = olFlagMarked
        .FlagRequest = "Follow up"
        .ReminderTime = datDue & " 17:00 PM"
        .ReminderOverrideDefault = True
        .ReminderSet = True
        .TaskStartDate = Date
        .TaskDueDate = datDue
        .Save
        .Send

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you running the code from? Excel?

Comment: You should check the current [rules](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Manage-messages-by-using-rules-80cc1f28-533d-4879-a8cc-ef83e9af0495) in the receiving inbox.  There is a default rule that strips categories from incoming emails (the assumption is the rule means something to the sender, but not the recipient).

Comment: Hi, the environment is the same as last week - the code doesn't do the highlight in red, flagged and reminder triggering for the recipient.

Comment: May not be a VBA problem. Send mail manually where there is a "Flag for Recipients" to see if this flag remains on the mail.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `OutApp` isn't useful and should be `Application` as you use this directly in Outlook.

I just test that code and it works nicely for me (Outlook 2013) :

```
Sub wittman()
    Dim OutMail As MailItem
    Dim datDue As Date

    datDue = DateAdd("d", 7, Date)
    Set OutMail = Application.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "test@mail.com"
        .Subject = "test"
        .HTMLBody = "msg"

        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .FlagStatus = olFlagMarked
        .FlagRequest = "Follow up"
        .ReminderTime = datDue & " 17:00 PM"
        .ReminderOverrideDefault = True
        .ReminderSet = True
        .TaskStartDate = Date
        .TaskDueDate = datDue
        .Save
        .Send
    End With 'OutMail
End Sub
```

Comment: *It doesn't work* doesn't help @R3uK help you.  Can you describe how it does not work (I see an error message, the email appeared but did not send, etc, etc)?

Comment: Tested Outlook 2010.  Works.  I cannot see anything obvious that 2007 did not support.

Comment: The code should highlight in red and put a reminder for the recipient in their Outlook - not to me. That it did but stupid me i change something and it doesn't work - it just sends the email and the recipient will see the email as normal email and the reminder doesn't trigger for them and the email on their mailbox is not flagged.

Comment: @wittman : I'm sorry mate, I haven't Office 2007 so I tried to find some info about this but I found nothing helpful... I can't figure out what is different with Outlook 2007 that may cause this... Sorry I can't help you more!

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a task to a delegate:

```
Sub AssignTask() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem 
 Dim myDelegate As Outlook.Recipient 
 Set MyItem = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem) 
 MyItem.Assign 
 Set myDelegate = MyItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myDelegate.Resolve 
 If myDelegate.Resolved Then 
   myItem.Subject = "Prepare Agenda for Meeting" 
   myItem.DueDate = Now + 30 
   myItem.Display 
   myItem.Send 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Don't forget to replace 'Eugene Astafiev' with a valid recipient name before running this example.

Also you may use the [MarkAsTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869791.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the MailItem class to mark a `MailItem` object as a task and assigns a task interval for the object. Calling this method sets the value of several other properties, depending on the value provided in `MarkInterval`. For more information about the properties set by specifying MarkInterval, see [OlMarkInterval Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868356.aspx).

You may find the [How to set a flag to follow up using VBA](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/set-flag-follow-up-using-vba/) article helpful.

Comment: Hi, MarkAsTask is for sent or received - i want to mark as task for the recipient - on their mailbox not on mine.

Comment: Try to use task items then. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: Hi, the problem with task is that they must accept the task. What i am trying to do is set a reminder for them - that way they will not complain about the extra thing they must do.